# Pandas gropuby[['col_name', 'values from another dataframe']]

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two very large pandas dataframes, `df` and `df_new`

Sample `df`:

```
A       B          DU          DR
100     103       -2          -10
100     110       -8          -9
100     112        0          -4
100     105        2           0
100     111        NAN         12
.
.
.
264     100        NAN         -15
.
.
.
```

Sample `df_new`:

```
A      TD 
100    0
100    1
100    2
.
.
.
103    0
103    1
.
.
.
```

I wish to get another pandas dataframe with count of `B` whose `DU` is less than or equal to `TD` of `df_new` for the same  value of `A` in both `df` and `df_new`. Similary I need count of `B`'s whose `DU` is greater than `TD` of `df_new` for the same  value of `A` (it should also include count of `np.nan`).
 i.e:
my expected dataframe should be something like this:

```
A      TD    Count_Less    Count_More 
100     0     3               2
100     1     3               2
100     2     4               1
.
.
.
103     0     0               5
103     1     1               4
.
.
.
```

How can I do this in Python?

Please note the data size is huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join for one Dataframe, then compare columns by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for `>` and 
[`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) for `<=` to new columns with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and last aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = df_new.merge(df.assign(DU = df['DU'].fillna(df_new['TD'].max() + 1)), on='A', how='left')
df2 = (df1.assign(Count_Less=df1['DU'].le(df1['TD']).astype(int), 
               Count_More=(df1['DU'].gt(df1['TD'])).astype(int))
         .groupby(['A','TD'], as_index=False)['Count_Less','Count_More'].sum()
         )
print (df2)
     A  TD  Count_Less  Count_More
0  100   0           3           2
1  100   1           3           2
2  100   2           4           1
3  103   0           0           0
4  103   1           0           0
```

Another solution with custom function, but slow if large DataFrame `df_new`:

```
df1 = df.assign(DU = df['DU'].fillna(df_new['TD'].max() + 1))
def f(x):
    du = df1.loc[df1['A'].eq(x['A']), 'DU']
    Count_Less = du.le(x['TD']).sum()
    Count_More = du.gt(x['TD']).sum()
    return pd.Series([Count_Less,Count_More], index=['Count_Less','Count_More'])

df_new = df_new.join(df_new.apply(f, axis=1))
print (df_new)
     A  TD  Count_Less  Count_More
0  100   0           3           2
1  100   1           3           2
2  100   2           4           1
3  103   0           0           0
4  103   1           0           0
```

Comment: your code works for sample data but crashes for my original data. Is there any better way to do this without crashing? Also your code doesn't count np.nan in greater count... Kindly check my updated question.

Comment: @yaminigoel - First solution need a lot of RAM, second is slowier if large dataframe. Please check edited answer. also count NaNs like `gt` with replace by value of `df_new['TD'].max() + 1)`